# How to use pixel perfect collision with two images pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame, pixel-perfect

Note: I do *not* want to use pygame sprites.

I am making a simple game and I need a way to detect if two images overlap using pixel-perfect collision in pygame. All the answers I have found so far require that I use pygame sprites, which I prefer not to use because I have less control over the objects.

(These images have transparent backgrounds)

Comment: The usual way is to make a per-pixel bit-mask of which pixels are considered part of the collision.  Determine whether the rectangles surrounding the images have overlapped, then compare the bit-masks of the overlapped-region to see if there is an overlap of important pixels.  I'm interested in your reasons for *not* wanting to use pygame sprites!  Could you expand on the reasons for this?

Comment: @Kingsley First, thanks for the suggestion on bitmasks. My only problem is that I don't know how to generate and/or compare them. To answer your question, It is possible that I don't understand sprites as well as I should, but from the little I looked at them it seemed like I would end up with less control -- Maybe I should look into it more.

Comment: Yeah, they are little bit of work - at first, but making your own sprites (which is what you propose) is a *lot more* work!  I think you have full control with sprites.  Maybe have a go, I'm waiting for your questions :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't be afraid of Sprites.

A [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) is just a simple class with an image (a `Surface` that is stored in the `image` attribute) and the size and position of the image (a `Rect` stored in the rect attribute).

So when you use a class like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, image, pos):
        self.image = image
        self.pos = pos

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.pos)
```

you could simple use the `Sprite` class instead, since not much would change:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = image.get_rect(center=pos)
```

Instead, it becames simpler, because we can let pygame handle blitting the image to the screen.

So, to use pixel perfect collision, you can use pygame's [`Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) class. Use `pygame.mask.from_surface` to create a `Mask` from your `Surface`, and use [`pygame.mask.Mask.overlap`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) to check if two masks overlap.

It's easier to use when you use the Sprite class, since you could just use functions like [`spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) together with [`collide_mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask).

But if you don't want to use the `Sprite` class, just take a look how `collide_mask` is [implemented](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/master/src_py/sprite.py#L1475) to see how you can use masks:

```
def collide_mask(left, right):
    xoffset = right.rect[0] - left.rect[0]
    yoffset = right.rect[1] - left.rect[1]
    try:
        leftmask = left.mask
    except AttributeError:
        leftmask = from_surface(left.image)
    try:
        rightmask = right.mask
    except AttributeError:
        rightmask = from_surface(right.image)
    return leftmask.overlap(rightmask, (xoffset, yoffset))
```